# Следует ли заключать ники (nicknames) в кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, оформление-текста

Допустим, у меня есть некоторый стихотворный текст. В конце я указываю его авторов:

> Константин Бугров, aka «Кот» и Виталий Деревянченко, aka «Огнев»

Следует ли заключать ники (прозвища, клички) «Кот» и «Огнев» в кавычки? А если ник выглядит как-то так: «Mracobess» или «S@S»?

Да, и еще, нужно ли ставить в конце точку?

Comment: Думаю, что запятая перед "aka" целевой аудитории будет, скорее всего, резать глаз. Независимо от того, насколько она оправдана.

Comment: А для нецелевой аудитории (за пределами форумов и блогов) само aka будет выглядеть неуместным, как и английская постановка прозвища между именем и фамилией (в английском нужны и запятая, и кавычки - кроме случая полного составного псевдонима типа Nat King Cole).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прозвища пишутся без кавычек и в тех случаях, когда прозвище стоит после имени (**Всеволод Большое Гнездо, Ричард Львиное Сердце), и тогда, когда прозвище располагается между именем и фамилией: Гарик Бульдог Харламов.
клички животных не заключаются в кавычки и пишутся с прописной буквы: пес Барбос, кот Матроскин, котенок Гав, лев Бонифаций.** Однако если индивидуальные названия употребляются в качестве обобщенных названий животных, они пишутся со строчной буквы: мурка, жучка, барбос, савраска, буренка. Со строчной буквы без кавычек пишутся и названия пород животных: корова холмогорка, собака пудель.

> Названия, написанные латиницей, тоже не берутся в кавычки.
>
> Точка нужна.

См.:Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2006 (и более поздние издания).

Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку. Прописная или строчная? – 7-е изд. – М., 2005.

Comment: В каком из русских источников допускается вставление прозвища между именем и фамилией? В английском языке это обычно (там вставляется ещё и в кавычках, чтобы отличать его от реального второго имени), поэтому может восприниматься как подражание.

Comment: @– Alex_ander, я вас не очень понял, о чем вы? Об этом: Гарик Бульдог Харламов?

Comment: Да, например это.

Comment: Эта практика пришла из Америки. Ср.: John «The Beard» Smith,Andreas Nikolaus „Niki“ Lauda,.